# Show that $∀f∈\mathcal{H}(Ω)$ with $|f^{(n)}(0)|<1$, there exists an entire function $\tilde{f}$ with $f=\tilde{f}_{|Ω}$

Tags: complex-analysis

**What to prove**:

Supone that $Ω$ is a domain in the complex plane with $0∈Ω$. Consider the family:
$$\mathcal{F} = \left\{ f ∈ \mathcal{H}(Ω):\ |f^{(n)}(0)|<1,\ ∀n≥0 \right\}$$

Show that for every function $f∈\mathcal{F}$, exists an entire function $\tilde{f}$ with $f=\tilde{f}_{|Ω}$.

---

**What I've tried**:

I've only been able to show that $\mathcal{F}$ is a normal family since:
$$ |f(z)| ≤ \sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{|f^{n}(0)|}{n!}|z|^n  ≤ \sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{|z|^n}{n!} = e^{|z|}$$

so $\mathcal{F}$ is uniformly bounded over compacts in $Ω$, and by Paul-Montel we know that $\mathcal{F}$ is normal.

But I don't know how to continue. Any help?

Comment: Isn't it enough to show that the power series of $f$ at $0$ has radius of convergence $= \infty$? In such a case, you can trivially extend $f$ to the whole plane.

Comment: ^My thought exactly, but I've just started complex analysis so I was hesitant to say this.

Comment: @Crostul would you mind telling me how to perform such an extension?. I've never done it or seen it during the course.

Comment: Just define $g(z)$ as the power series of $f$. Then, you prove that the radius of convergence is $\infty$ and you are done.

Comment: @HasanSaad oops , thanks a lot!